# Quoted argument in Autocomplete

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a bash autocomplete that works ONLY when the argument is a single word.  I can autocomplete quoted statements to then use in a case statement for tagging files (think meta-data tagging which sometimes require more than one word.)

Is there a way to get the autocomplete to display directories after a particular option?  Script below:

```
_script()
{
        local cur prev opts iter
        COMPREPLY=()
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
        prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
        opts="-t"
        if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
                COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
                return 0
        fi
        case "$prev" in
                -t)
                        option="single \"double\ word\""
                        option="${option//\\ /___}"
                        for iter in $option; do
                                if [[ $iter =~ ^$cur ]]; then
                                        COMPREPLY+=( "${iter//___/ }" )
                                fi
                        done
                        return 0
                        ;;
                "single"|"double word")
                        compopt -o default
                        COMPREPLY=()
                        return 0
                        ;;
        esac
}
complete -F _script script
```

When I use it as such:

`script -t <tab>`: it shows me the proper options: `single "double word"` and does NOT display directories (yay! this is what I want!)

If I use:

`script -t single <tab>`: it shows me available directories (yay! this is what I want!)

If I use:

`script -t "double word" <tab>`: **it outputs nothing on the tab.  That is what I am looking to fix.**

Comment: There is an unpaired double quote in `option="single \"double\ word\"`. Is that a copy&paste error? If not then I would be surprised that it works at all.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - correct, it was a typo. Fixed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of `double word` is wrong (though it makes more sense than what the shell, at least bash, does); thus it is not recognized in the `case`.

You can see what happens if you put `set -x` at the top of the function code (or before the line you are interested in).

You return the correct string, `"double word"`, with the `"` being part of the word as programmable completion sees it. It is a bit strange as the quotes are recognized so that `"double word"` is just one word but they are not removed so that the `_script` function does see them. In consequence completion works with `"double word"` but not with `double\ word` although it is the same to the shell on execution. So this is a counter-intuitive mix of literal and parsed command line strings.

### Solution

Your code works if you replace

```
"single"|"double word"
```

with

```
"single"|"\"double word\""
```

or even better with

```
"single"|"\"double word\""|"double\ word"|"'double word'"
```

### Suggestion

I would like to suggest a few more changes, though:

```
_script()
{ 
        local cur prev opts iter
        COMPREPLY=()
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
        prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
        opts="-t"
        if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
                COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
                return 0
        fi
        case "$prev" in
                -t)
                        options=(single "double\ word")
                        for iter in "${options[@]}"; do
                                if [[ $iter =~ ^$cur ]]; then
                                        COMPREPLY+=( "$iter" )
                                fi
                        done
                        return 0
                        ;;
                "single"|"double\ word")
                        compopt -o default
                        COMPREPLY=()
                        return 0
                        ;;
        esac
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm -- would you mind explaining the change you made in the `-t)` portion for my education? Specifically the `for loop` portion?

Comment: @chow The loop goes over several elements and an array is the natural way of storing several elements. That easily avoids the quoting problem you run into when concatenating elements (which contain the separator char) into a string. Strings are not made for that and thus they are not good at it. See the "Arrays" block in the bash man page.